# Running SWT from a RCP app

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

Can I run my swt code in a rcp application, when I am running in swt it works fine when trying to do so from rcp app getting:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4263)`

Comment: How about some code? What exactly are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is based on SWT so you can re-use your code. But you cannot reuse your GUI. You have to create a `View` instead. Try to google for an example, there are many.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a view in plugin.xml first then you can re-use your SWT code with very little modification.